# How to update context state variable rendering across screens in React native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-flatlist, react-context

new to React Native.
I'm using Context hook state to use an array in two tab screens of an application.

One of the screens displays the context array in the form of a FlatList, the other one inserts items into the array. What would be the proper way to rerender when the array changes?

Here's the code:

APP.JS

```
 const App = () => {

   const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();

   return(
 
   <NavigationContainer>
       <Tab.Screen name="HomeScreen"  component={Home} />
       <Tab.Screen name="DiscoverScreen" component={Discover} />
   </NavigationContainer>

  );
}


export default function AppWrapper() {
  return (
    <AuthProvider>
      <App />
    </AuthProvider>
  );
 }
```

AUTHCONTEXT.JS

```
 const AuthContext = createContext()

 const AuthProvider = ({ children }) => {

 const [array, setArray] = useState([]);

 return (
     <AuthContext.Provider value={{ array, setArray }}>
        {children}
     </AuthContext.Provider>
  )
 }

 export {AuthContext, AuthProvider}
```

HOME.JS

```
export default Home = () => {

  const {array} = useContext(AuthContext);

  return(

     <View>
        <FlatList 
          data={array}
          renderItem={(item)=>{ 
          return(
             <Text>{item}</Text>
          )}}
          />
     </View>

    )
  }
```

DISCOVER.JS

```
 export default Discover = () => {

 const {setArray} = useContext(AuthContext);

 setArray((currentArray)=>[...currentArray,'test']);

 return(
    <View></View>
 );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't invoke `setArray` unconditionally in `Discover` function component. If you need to add value to the `array` when component appears, use `useEffect` hook (and don't forget to setup second argument, probably it will be empty array, otherwise you get into infinite loop and component crash with an error)

```
 export default Discover = () => {

 const {setArray} = useContext(AuthContext);

 useEffect(() => {
   setArray((currentArray)=>[...currentArray,'test']);
 }, [])
 
 return(
    <View></View>
 );
}
```

And you don't need to worry about rerender the component, React handle this for you. Once `setArray` invokes it automatically rerender all component that use `AuthContext` and their children.